# I have a Kindle book with a deviating font, can I change it to normal?

Tags: fonts, kindle-for-android

Most of the books on my Kindle for Android app display with the same font, which I find good enough for reading.

[image]

But I have just one book which uses different typography, and it is bad enough to distract me from the reading experience. I checked maybe 10 other books and none displays that way. So I assume that this must be a publisher font. Kindle is supposed to support reset of publisher fonts since 4.3. I have 4.4.0.71 and can't find how to do it. A [solution from Amazon help](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/forums/kindleqna?ie=UTF8&cdForum=Fx2GRKKY25FZOBK&cdThread=Tx22XX2E8PWI819) says

> 1. While reading, press the Menu button and then select Change Font Size.
> 2. Next to Publisher Font, select "on" or "off".

But I have no such option.

**If this is a publisher font, how do I get it to normal? If it isn't, why is this book displaying so differently from all the others, and again, how do I get it to normal?** (device is not rooted).

The below screenshot shows what I see in the settings for the book. (There are no font settings in the two real Menu buttons, this comes from the `aA` button which changes the book's appearance). It also shows the strange font with low readability (both screenshots are taken at the same line spacing setting).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You [cannot change the font](http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdThread=Tx3E8I4TQ6APSM3) on some books if it's using an older format.

> Because those books are older topaz format instead of newer AZW
>   format. You can't change the font type with the topaz format, although
>   you can still change the font size. If you look at the content of
>   Kindle with your computer, you will notice that the books with the
>   older topaz format has .tpz extension while the newer AZW format has
>   .AZW extension.